# How unusual is this case?

Tags: phd, postdocs, career-path

I learned of the following career case: a student was accepted into a PhD program (some sub-discipline of physics) with stellar grades and theses. The PhD nearly failed - normally the PhD takes four years in this department and should result in some three or four papers, but after four years the student had nothing. He was not paid salary and had to earn money elsewhere, still staying in contact with the department (and living in the same city). He managed to finish his PhD 10 (!) years (instead of four) and now has a research career going, being employed at another rather good University as a post-doc with several publications.

I wonder if there is some similar example in Mathematics and how unusual would it be for something like this to happen where the person recovers the career after four years of no research output.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Would it be ... *How does a PhD (candidate) recover their career after four years of no (near nonexistent) research output?*

Comment: The question is rather if there are known similar cases in Mathematics.

Comment: Please choose a title which actually describes your question. Titles should help other people with the same problem find the question.

Answer (score 6):

I hoped to graduate, post bachelors, in four years, but had a setback, partly due to burnout after the intense BA degree. I recovered and finished in seven. That isn't terribly unusual. But the drop-off per year is likely pretty steep, so ten for a successful outcome is pretty rare.

Everyone's case is different. Life intrudes. More to the point, however, is that true research is open ended and success can't be predicted or scheduled. Some people finish earlier by cutting scope when it gets harder. Some just push on.

Having a truly successful outcome after ten years could just be the difficulty of the problem attacked. Solving a very difficult problem, even in ten years, could put you in a good place for a career. The result is more important than the time it took to achieve it.

Unusual yes, but not especially surprising. Good luck to them.

Comment: That is an inspiring story. May I ask then, since you are now a professor, how you explained your delay during the post-doc interviews? Did you mention the burnout? Did you get good results that "compensated" the delay in graduation? Were you strictly inactive during some phase of the PhD or was everything simply slowed down?

Comment: I never had a postdoc. There were no gaps in my studies, but I changed institutions. My dissertation was quite remarkable, but I graduated into a dead academic market so my career didn't really take off for several years. It would have been quite different had I finished in 4.

Comment: Then how did you make a living between graduation and the next academic job? Was this a permanent position? 

I take it that you mean by "remarkable" that your thesis was VERY good? 

Was the switch from Mathematics to Computer Science difficult?

Comment: There were no gaps, just a teaching focused job at a small college. I love teaching so it wasn't a problem. The pay was good and the location outstanding. I had a family by that time. Thesis was outstanding, actually. A complete math theory within Analysis. Another career issue was that the interest in math moved to other fields about that time. This was 50 years ago.

Comment: What's your thesis? May I appreciate it?

Comment: @Michael, not if I'm to maintain anonymity. It was very deep into classical real analysis, bringing together some threads created a generation earlier by some superstars. But of little use to advance the path I had to follow. It was also right at the cusp where the field fell out of favor. Alas.